# Radiation levels around Mars

Tags: mars, radiation

What is the typical amount of radiation levels that a spacecraft would experience when orbiting Mars? is there any formula with which a person could estimate the net radiation experienced at different altitudes and inclination around Mars?

Answer (score 1):

After going through many technical papers for the question i myself has poised i have come up with one conclusion.
As Mars has a very low strength Magnetic field unlike that of Earths,the levels of radiation around the orbit should be similar to the Radiation levels which are present on the surface.
please correct me if the above statement is wrong.

Radiation levels as observed by RAD on MSL

[image]

Comment: The factors that influence difference in radiation in Mars orbit vs surface: 1) difference in time of exposure to solar radiation (higher orbit remains in sunlight longer; surface shielded 50% of the time), 2) atmospheric shielding, 3) particles captured by the soil; secondary radiation. Since 1. and 2. substract, and 3. adds to radiation, they mostly cancel each other out, the final figure becoming quite similar to orbital.